# How to get sum of the numbers in each string

Tags: python, string, split, sum, integer

This is what I have done so far:

I have converted excel data to list

combined all the hourly data lists into one list

used split function to remove all commas and spaces between the numbers

used split function again to separate group of data by every 12 zeros

Now I'm trying to sum all the numbers that are separated into each string how would I do this?

Here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_excel("2010.xlsx")
df2 = df.to_numpy()
df3 = df2[0:366, 1:25]
list1 = df3.tolist()
list2 = (list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list1)))
b = ''.join(str(list2).split(','))
c = ''.join(str(b).split(' '))
e = c.split('0'*12)
```

printing this code gives something like:

['[', '', '000000000100111101', '', '', '0000112112111101011100000000001', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0000002433151111000001223221', '', '', '', '', ]

so I'm trying to add all the numbers in '000000000100111101' and '0000112112111101011100000000001' and so on

Comment: Looks like you need to convert strings into numbers. You could use `int` to do it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-string-to-integer-in-python/

Comment: do you want to sum the numbers in each string, i.e. 000000000100111101 should sum to 6?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want, but try this

```
import numpy as np
e = ['[', '', '000000000100111101', '', '', '0000112112111101011100000000001', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '0000002433151111000001223221', '', '', '', '', ]


tot = np.zeros(len(e))
for idx, item in enumerate(e):
    for i in item:
        if i.isdigit():
            tot[idx] += int(i)

print(tot)
```

producing this output

```
print(tot)
[ 0.  0.  6.  0.  0. 17.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.
  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 35.  0.
  0.  0.  0.]
```